# Ida cannot open. a files of esp32 (Xtensa)

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, elf, esp

I tried to open this file with IDA Pro

https://github.com/espressif/esp32-wifi-lib/blob/master/esp32/libpp.a

Ida detect that is ELF for Xtensa (relocatable)

But when I tired to open it I got

```
Undefined or unknown machine type 94
```

What can I do please?

Answer (score 1):

Xtensa support has been added in [IDA 7.7](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/news/7_7/).